# Beginner, Python Class Not Printing

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm a beginner. I'm doing my best. Please go easy on me. My task is to create a class called "person" with one method "hello" and one attribute "name" which represents the name of a person. In the end it should print "My name is X and I am a Y, where X is the sys.argv[1] name and Y is the name of the class. I'm supposed to instantiate an object of the class, run the hello method and print the name of the class. My brain is a bit fried and I'm at a loss. Please help. I feel like I'm moving in circles and getting no where. Here's what I've got so far:

```
import sys

class person():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def hello(self):
        print(f'My name is {self.name} and I am a {__class__.__name__}.')
        print(person1.hello())

person(sys.argv[1])

person1=person(sys.argv[1])  

print(str(person.__class__))
```

So far its not printing anything at all.

Comment: The program has a `print()` statement, so it must be printing _something_.  Try adding a plain print such as `print("Hello")`, just to see if it appears.

Comment: What are you doing on the command line? It's not possible to call print on an object and not print _something_ (excepting some more advanced Python stuff you have definitely not done.)

Answer (score 1):

This one is working.

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def hello(self):
        print(f'My name is {self.name} and I am a {__class__.__name__}.')


my_person = Person('John')
my_person.hello()
```

The Output:

```
My name is John and I am a person.
```

Suggestion:
For convention classes are named with first letter Capital to distinguish of the instances.